# How to add button in GVRPanoramaView?

Tags: ios, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am creating **VR Base app**. In which I want to show a room in 360. For that I have used `GVRPanoramaView`. That is Google Cardboard. This is also working fine. When I have create view with `GVRPanoramaView`. It worked and my room is loaded.

I have two query.

1) Currently in the app to scroll user need to rotate device in particular direction. that means app is working base on the gyroscope. But I also want to scroll using user drag. Can it be possible? If not in google cardboard then can suggest me other?

2) I the app in the room I want to add a button in such a way that when user click on that to fire event. This button should be scroll with particular object. Check for that reference image. [image]

Comment: did you managed to do part 2??

Answer (score 0):

(project owner here) 
For 1), there's an [open issue](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/132) on the project's github. Hopefully we'll have this in a few weeks.

For now we're a bit unsure about 2), as it means adding some UI in 3D, which clients will surely want to customize, which will lead to a complex API to maintain. We might offer something very minimalistic at some point, but have no clear timeline for it yet.